# Extend Pandoc with custom Markdown syntax

Tags: r, lua, latex, r-markdown, pandoc

I want to extend R Markdown with the following syntactic sugar for acronyms:

```markdown
The (WHO:: World Health Organization) is an agency of the (UN:: United Nations)
```

which should be translated to the following raw LaTeX with `\nomenclature`

```latex
The WHO\nomenclature{WHO}{World Health Organization} is an agency of the UN\nomenclature{UN}{United Nations}
```

and after compilation I would see a glossary page and this text:

```
The WHO is an agency of the UN
```

I figured out, that Pandoc has Lua filters, but I'm not a Lua (or Haskel) programmer and It's hard for me to understand where I'm wrong:

```lua
– get an entire paragraph from AST
function Para(s)
    -- match new syntax: (ACRONYM:: definition)
    before, acronym, definition, after = tostring(s):match("(.*)%((.*)::(.-)%)(.*)")

    -- if matched
    if acronym then
        -- interpolate new paragrath string
        new = string.format('%s%s\\nomenclature{%s}{%s}%s', before, acronym, acronym, definition, after)
        -- return new AST element
        return pandoc.read(new)
    else
        return s
    end

end
```

Unfortunately, I see raw `Para` structure in an output PDF.

Comment: You should put together a *complete* example that other can run and see what you saw.

Comment: I'd recommend you use a [native span](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#divs-and-spans) instead of your custom syntax, which is much easier to match on in a filter...